# How to create a root node in a linked list?

Tags: java, memory, linked-list

I'm trying to learn linked-lists in Java and had some questions about the code below:

```
public class List {
    Node root;
    public List() {
        // constructor
    }

    public int pop() {
        // pop logic
    }

    public int push(int data) {
        // push logic
    }
}
```

I'd like to have a List class for popping and pushing data into the linked list. However, since the list won't have any default data on instantiation, what would be the best way for storing a reference to the root node?

In C, I would just have a pointer like:

```
Node * root;
```

But since Java does not have pointer, would having a simple declaration like:

```
Node root;
```

... be acceptable? I haven't used Java in a while, but doesn't allocating memory to an object declared as a class variable cause potential memory issues? Thanks!

Comment: Variables store values. For non-primitive types these values are (internally) "the reference" to the object, or null. I prefer to use the term "names", e.g. `Node n1 = new Node(); Node n2 = n1;` -> the new Node "is named by" n1 and n2 (it is the *same* Node object) as both variables will "evaluate to" the same object. This behavior similar to pointers in C/C++. For non-primitive types there is *no* implicit copy/duplicate/clone on an assignment (or when passing to a method); this differs from copy-constructors in C++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a simple declaration like `Node root` is acceptable. It is not actually a pointer, but a reference that can potentially refer to any `Node`.

References in Java are conceptually equivalent to C pointers, but are less flexible and use a simpler syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
Node root;
```

Is acceptable. Every non-primitive object (including arrays of primitives or objects) in Java is actually a reference to an object, so it is like a C pointer in many ways.

It is actually so much like a pointer, that this declaration by itself isn't actually creating an object. It is a reference that is not pointing to anything yet, and if you try to use `root` before assigning it to a `new Node()` first, you will get a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `Node root;` is absolutely fine. Just make sure you don't change the value of `root`. For using it, create another variable, for traversing a path: `Node start = root;` This way `root` remains untouched.

```
I haven't used Java in a while, but doesn't allocating memory to an object declared as a class variable cause potential memory issues?
```

No it doesn't. While simply writing `Node root;` doesn't allocate any memory, `root = new Node();` does. Take a note here that `class members` in java are static, the non-static members are `global variables`. Allocating memory to global variables in java is a common practice. For example, the variable where you actually store the list, *will* be a global variable, and you *will* have to allocate memory to it.

Java has a robust memory management system, so you won't run into memory issues too easily.